# Mixing object props and strings in a List<object>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

working in .net mvc
I have a jQuery plugin consuming a List column for column where the controller outputs:

```
            usersData.Add(new List<object>
            {
                user.ID,
                user.FullName,
                user.Email,
                user.Company.Name,
                user.DateCreated.ToString(),
                string.Empty
            });
```

I want to combine objects with string literal so that jQuery gets objects like:

user.FullName + '
' + user.Company.Name

Normally, this would be easy to do in the view but the nature of the 'column-to-column' mapping on the part of the plug-in means that the concatenation has to take place in the controller.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
usersData.Add(new List<object>
{
    user.ID,
    user.FullName + " " + user.Company.Name,
    user.Email,
    user.DateCreated.ToString(),
    string.Empty
});
```

Comment: arrgg...i've been working in tsql too much lately...i'd tried user.FullName + ' ' + user.Company.Name, .

thx

Comment: I know the feeling. I tend to type "or" in C# and "||" in sql quite often.